# Rsync daemon to mirror local files in WSL

Tags: linux, rsync, wsl2

I want to mirror `C:\path\to\docs` to `E:\path\to\mirror` using an rsync daemon launched as a WSL service. Both drive C and E are on the same computer. I understand that:

```
rsync -rtvuc -delete source_folder/ dest_folder/
```

... is the command to mirror a folder.  However I don't know how to write an `rsyncd.conf` to do this command as a background system service/daemon.

As for the WSL part, I've done some looking and think I just need to place a .bat file in my startup folder. Is that correct?

Thanks for any input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a few years since I've used `rsync`, and longer since I've used `rsyncd`, so I'll welcome correction if I'm off-base on anything, but I did a little research to brush-up before posting this, at least:

- Since you are simply mirroring local-to-local, you really don't have any need for the daemon.  The daemon is useful when you need it to run on another host that you control, and you don't need the security/overhead of running rsync-to-rsync over SSH.  See a few of [these answers](https://serverfault.com/questions/100707/rsync-daemon-is-it-really-useful), although I'm not sure I would consider any of them authoritative.
- You seem to be thinking that you can configure `rsynd` to continuously keep two directories in sync through configuration of `rsyncd.conf`.  Unfortunately, that's not how it works.  First, `rsyncd.conf` just allows you to configure paths on the remote server which you want to be able to access via your local `rsync`, and to specify options/permissions for those directories.
- See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12460279/11810933) for some details on ways in which you could potentially automatically keep two directories in sync whenever a file changes.  However, also note that the typical way of doing this is simply to run a cron job every so often that initiates a sync, rather than "watching" for file changes.
- Also note that under WSL2, "watching" for updates (known as the `inotify` mechanism) doesn't work on Windows drives (a.k.a. `/mnt/c`, `/mnt/d`).  It only works on the ext4 root filesystem in WSL.  WSL1 does not have this limitation.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63402588/11810933) and my answer there for some more details.
- So if you go the "recommended" route and set this up your command-line in the question as a cron job to run every (say) hour, you'll still need some way of getting `crond` to run.  And this comes back to part of your question about how to get a service to run at boot.

  For that, you *could* use a `.bat` file in your Startup folder, but my preferred approach is to use Windows Task Scheduler to schedule a task to run at logon.  Note that it will need to be logon rather than boot, since WSL does seem to have a requirement that the owning user be logged in to their Windows account.  Working around this *seems* to be possible (with stability caveats), but requires some PowerShell scripting to launch the process.

  To create the Scheduled Task, run Task Scheduler, then:

  1. Create a new folder in your Task Library named "WSL" (optional)
  2. In that folder, *Action -> Create Basic Task*
  3. *Name:* something like "WSL crond"
  4. *Trigger:* When I log on
  5. *Action:* Start a program
  6. *Program/script:* `wsl`
  7. *Add arguments:* `-u root -e sh -c "service cron status || service cron start"`
  8. *Finish*

  You can try this command-line in PowerShell to test it out in advance with `wsl -u root -e sh -c "service cron status || service cron start"`.  It starts WSL using the root user so that you can run the `service` command without a password.  It then checks to see if the `cron` service is currently running and, if not, starts it.

  Note that this assumes you are running Ubuntu or a distribution that includes the init scripts for crond.  Some distributions such as Debian that are more "purely" Systemd based do not include these.

This answer has gotten long enough as it is, so I'm not going to cover exactly how to add a cron job, but if you need help with that, see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/2368/1165986).